# How to assign a new value in a column of a dataframe based on a value from a different column in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
P1   P2  P3_1  P3_2
1    3    1     30
2    NA   NA    NA
2    NA   NA    NA
2    NA   NA    NA
1    1    1     10
```

I'm trying to set all the NA's to be 0 instead of NA's if P1 = 2.

The code I have is

```
df$P2 <- ifelse(df$P1 == 2, df$P2, 0)
```

Which returns this

```
P1   P2  P3_1  P3_2
1    0    1     30
2    NA   NA    NA
2    NA   NA    NA
2    NA   NA    NA
1    0   1     10
```

It seems that P2 gets changed to 0 when P1 = 1 instead. I know I could just make it so all NA's are 0 instead, but this trend is specific for when the value is 2. Any other NA's I wouldn't want to change to 0.

Where did I go wrong with the `ifelse()` syntax? Is there a better way to do this and include all three columns that I need?

Comment: You only had to change the result i.e `ifelse(df$P1 == 2, 0, df$P2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we create a logical in `ifelse`, the 'yes' condition should be 0 and 'no' would be 'df$P2'.  Or without the `ifelse`, it can be assigned directly as well

```
df$P2[with(df, P1 == 2 & is.na(P2))] <- 0
```

-output

```
> df
  P1 P2 P3_1 P3_2
1  1  3    1   30
2  2  0   NA   NA
3  2  0   NA   NA
4  2  0   NA   NA
5  1  1    1   10
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(P1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), P2 = c(3, 0, 0, 0, 
1), P3_1 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), P3_2 = c(30L, NA, NA, NA, 10L
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```